# punctuation color in references

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, color

I have used the following command to change the color of references in the text to blue:

```
\hypersetup{ colorlinks,
pdfborder=0 0 0,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue}
```

however; the parentheses, semicolons and commas sometimes appear in black.

The only way I was able to fix this was by using the `\textcolor{blue}{\citeN{sampref1}}` so that all the text would appear in blue. But this is frustrating to do for more that 100 of references that I have. 
Is there a solution for this problem?

I am using `chicago` as my `bibliographystyle`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! By selecting text and clicking the button marked `{}` above the text field, it will be highlighted as code (blocks are indented with four spaces, words enclosed in backticks, `\``).

Comment: Can you please add a minimal document that shows the problem? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following lines into your preamble of your document.

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\NAT@open{\color{blue}(}}
\makeatother
```

(This is assuming you are using `natbib`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\bibpunct` command to modify the citation style.

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{a}{\textcolor{blue}{,}}{,}
\begin{document}
     ...
\end{document}
```